# Mocking the value of an imported selector in Karma unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx, karma-coverage

Currently trying to mock out a selectors value in my unit tests with Karma. The code I'm trying to mock is the following:

```
Constructor(private store: Store<IAppState> {
    this.isFound$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectIsFound),filter(isFound => isFound != undefined))
}
```

I need something that will let me mock out the selectIsFound value instead of mocking out the isFound observable so the filter can be tested and I can get code coverage up. If there is another solution without the filter operator that would also help.

I'm currently mocking the observable values directly using:

```
component.isFound = of(true)
```

But I need something that'll trigger the filter so it can get coverage.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete code. There are some variables we don't know where do they come from

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `component.isFound = of(true)` is not enough.
You need to follow `ngrx` testing guide and to provide a mock selector: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // ...
      providers: [
        // ...
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ],
    });

    // setting the selected value.
    TestBed.get(Store).overrideSelector(selectIsFound, true);
  });
```